# Vlookup returning error when item is in the list

Tags: vba, excel

Issue: Item is in VLOOKUP table, but is returning the value of "Missing" in the appropriate cell. When conUD prints if I copy paste it from the Debug window and Ctrl+F - find it on the J column it finds it without issue. Why would it be found by Ctrl+F and not VLookup?

Notes:

- This is only the relevant code, not the entire chunk.

  lrVelocity is calculating correctly. Value is 1,951 .

  The values are of the form 0001HCM8889W01 and thus do not violate the VLOOKUP max characters restriction.

  As you can see I tried to trim any invisible spaces as well as ensured they were both strings.

  I am reasonably new to VBA and appreciate any and all help with this issue. I read multiple Google articles, but none of those fixes solved my issue.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wsQuantity As Worksheet
Dim wsVelocity As Worksheet
Dim wsParameters As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim lrMain As Long 'lr = last row
Dim lrQuantity As Long
Dim lrVelocity As Long
Dim lrParameters As Long
Dim lrData As Long
Dim conUD As String 'con=concatenate
Dim conECD As String
Dim calcWeek As Long
Dim RC As Long 'Row Counter
Dim vl As Variant 'Vlookup, Variant to allow for errors without breaking the code

calcWeek = wsParameters.Range("B3").Value
lrVelocity = wsVelocity.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set wsMain = Worksheets("Main Tab")
Set wsVelocity = Worksheets("Velocity")

 For RC = 2 To 10 'lrVelocity
With wsVelocity
    .Cells(RC, 10) = .Cells(RC, 1) & .Cells(RC, 1) & .Cells(RC, 4) & .Cells(RC, 5) & .Cells(RC, 9)
    .Cells(RC, 10).Value = CStr(Trim(.Cells(RC, 10).Value))
    .Cells(RC, 11) = .Cells(RC, 6)
    .Cells(RC, 12) = .Cells(RC, 7)
    .Cells(RC, 13) = .Cells(RC, 8)
    .Cells(RC, 14) = .Cells(RC, 3)
    .Cells(RC, 22) = .Cells(RC, 1) & .Cells(RC, 9)
End With
Next RC

For RC=2 To 10
conUD = wsMain.Cells(RC, 21) & wsMain.Cells(RC, 4) & calcWeek
conUD = CStr(Trim(conUD))
Debug.Print conUD
wsVelocity.Activate
vl = Application.VLookup(conUD, wsVelocity.Range(wsVelocity.Cells(2, 10), wsVelocity.Cells(lrVelocity, 11)), 2, False)
If IsError(vl) Then
    wsMain.Cells(RC, 10).Value = "Missing"
Else
    wsMain.Cells(RC, 10).Value = vl
End If
Next RC
```

Comment: when you indicate it is "returning an Error", does this mean an error is raised? Or does this mean that the output is "Missing"?

Comment: It is returning the value "Missing". I'll add that to my post.

Comment: No special characters, only letters and numbers.

Comment: Do you check to see if `lrVelocity` is `Nothing` or what value it's returning? It looks like you're not setting the worksheet for the variable until after you use it for that find.

Comment: @user1274820 if the result of `.Find` method is nothing, then `Find().Row` will raise an Object Required error (unless there is an error handler that we're not seeing in this snippet).

Comment: I was also going to suggest using `Find` instead of `Application.VLookup` since it looks to me like the value is merely being plugged in.

Comment: When I Debug.Print vl I get Error 2042.  Googling now as I haven't seen it before. (Also I am about to step into a meeting, but will respond ASAP as I appreciate all the help!). I haven't used the .Find method before. How is it different the VLookup? Are there any things I need to be careful of when using it? (Correction: I /have/ used Find to find the last cell, but that was a copy pasted code, not one I developed.)

Comment: You're using `conUD = CStr(Trim(conUD))` to trim the search input, but are you sure your column data doesn't have any errant spaces?

Comment: @CLR the column values are built in the preceding loop: `.Cells(RC, 10).Value = CStr(Trim(.Cells(RC, 10).Value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @user1274820 is on to something. Normally we use `Application.Vlookup` as you're using, with the anticipation that perhaps the value will not be found in the first column of `table_array`, and you want to handle that with "Missing" value in the output.

**HOWEVER**, if the value *is* found, but the value in the return column (k, in your case) is an error, then the function will return the error as well. In your case, while the value *is* found in column J, it would seem that column K contains an `#N/A`. (Let me know if this is not the case!)

`Application.Vlookup` returns an `Error 2042` in both of these cases:

1. `lookup_value` is not found in the first column of `table_array` (most common usage & expectation, IMO)
2. `lookup_value` IS found, but the resulting value from `col_index_num` is itself an error.

So, if the return value might contain an error even if the lookup value exists, then we can't use `Application.Vlookup` to test for the presence of the value, **but you can use an alternate method** like `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` or `Application.Match`.

Here, we simply query the column J and use `CountIf` to ensure there's at least 1 matching value.  This will validate our `Vlookup` in advance, but we still need to handle the possible error in the return value.

```
For RC = 2 to 10
    conUD = wsMain.Cells(RC, 21) & wsMain.Cells(RC, 4) & calcWeek
    conUD = CStr(Trim(conUD))
    Debug.Print conUD
    With wsVelocity
        Dim lookupRange as Range
        Set lookupRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(lrVelocity, 11))
    End With
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(lookupRange.Columns(1), conUD) <> 0 Then
        'The value is found, it should be safe to use VLOOKUP 
        vl = Application.VLookup(conUD, lookupRange, 2, False)
        '## Handles an error in the return value from the return column
        If IsError(vl) Then
            '## Copies the error from return column, or modify as needed
            wsMain.Cells(RC, 10).Value = CVerr(vl)
        Else
            '## Value found in Col J and return Vlookup from Col K
            wsMain.Cells(RC, 10).Value = vl
        End If
    Else
        '## Value NOT FOUND in column J
        wsMain.Cells(RC, 10).Value = "Missing"
    End If
Next
```

## Update

From chat, I can see the formatting of your Main and Lookup tables values is different. In your lookup table, you're duplicating a prefix e.g., "0001HCM8889" and so you end up with "0001HCM8890001HCM889W01".

This is why `Find` or Ctrl+F will find the cell, but `VLOOKUP` won't, because it's requiring an exact match.

As it appears you're constructing/sanitizing the lookup table in your first loop, you should be able to fix it by doing this:

```
For RC = 2 To 10 'lrVelocity

    With wsVelocity
        '## Removed the duplicate .Cells(RC, 1) from the next line ##
        .Cells(RC, 10) = .Cells(RC, 1) & .Cells(RC, 4) & .Cells(RC, 5) & .Cells(RC, 9)
        .Cells(RC, 10).Value = CStr(Trim(.Cells(RC, 10).Value))
        .Cells(RC, 11) = .Cells(RC, 6)
        .Cells(RC, 12) = .Cells(RC, 7)
        .Cells(RC, 13) = .Cells(RC, 8)
        .Cells(RC, 14) = .Cells(RC, 3)
        .Cells(RC, 22) = .Cells(RC, 1) & .Cells(RC, 9)
    End With

Next RC
```

Comment: The values in K are not #N/A... They are all numbers of the form 88.8% . I'll try using .CountIf to check.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of some data?

Comment: Also, try implementing the code *as I've put it in the answer* and let's see what happens with this.

Comment: It throws "Type Mismatch" on the CountIf line.

Comment: Oops, I had the arguments backwards. Try `.CountIf(lookupRange.Columns(1), conUD)` instead.

Comment: Runs without error, but still fills in the cells as "Missing" ... I'll take a screenshot.

Comment: If it's running without error, then the `CountIf` is returning a value of 0.

Comment: Unless you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere above in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138251/discussion-between-emily-alden-and-david-zemens).